# How to route between internal child routes angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

I have two small projects (`Project 1 - abc, Project 2 - xyz`) that are merged into a single project. User must be authenticated to access the second project whereas the first project can be accessed without authentication. How should I add my `route.navigate` method to

1. route internally among those projects? - Say from a child route in `project abc` to a child route in `project xyz` (myproject.com/abc/compA to myproject.com/xyz/login)
2. route between child components of `project xyz` (myproject.com/xyz/compA to myproject.com/xyz/compB)

```html
    {
        path: 'abc',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'compA',
                component: CompA,
                ...
            }, {
                path: 'compB',
                ...
            }, {
                path: "**",
                redirectTo: "compA"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        path: 'xyz',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivate: [MetaGuard],
                pathMatch: "full",
                redirectTo: 'home'
            }, {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
                ...
            }, {
                path: 'home',
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
                ...
            }, {
                path: 'compA',
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
                ...
            }, {
                path: 'compB',
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
                ...
            }, {
                path: 'compC',
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
                ...
            }, {
                path: "**",
                redirectTo: 'home'
            }
        ]
    }
```

My folder structure is identical to this:

[image]

Comment: Have you created two layouts for two projects?

Comment: Yes, each project has it's own folder with all of it's components. But this is the only routing component that routes to both the projects.

Comment: I have added a image that shows how my folder structure looks like.